# Create data structure from different sized dictionaries python3.x

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to create a list of dictionaries and export to a csv file. These dictionaries vary in length - basically I would like to do something like the following:

```
a = {'name': 'Alison', 'food1': 'bananas', 'food2': 'apples', 'food3': 'dates'}
b = {'name': 'Ken', 'food1': 'noodles', 'food2': 'rice'}
c = {'name': 'Max', 'food1': 'jello', 'food2': 'yogurt', 'food3': 'bananas', 'food4': 'milk}
```

output csv

```
   name      |    food1    |     food2     |    food3    |     food4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Alison     |   bananas   |     apples    |     dates   |      ' '
  Ken        |   noodles   |      rice     |      ' '    |      ' '
  Max        |    jello    |     yogurt    |    bananas  |      milk

# list of dictionaries
data = [a, b, c]
```

Currently, I have code that allows for creating a data structure from a list of dictionaries as long as each dictionary in that list has the same number of keys.

```
keys = data[0].keys()

with open('profiles.csv', 'w', newline = '') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

Does someone have a way to merge a list of dictionaries that vary in length into a csv as shown above?

Comment: Consider using a `defaultdict` or `pandas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible Pandas solution. This also makes it more convenient to write to a file with `df.to_csv` method. If you prefer `' '` to `NaN`, you can add `df = df.fillna(' ')`.

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'name': 'Alison', 'food1': 'bananas', 'food2': 'apples', 'food3': 'dates'}
b = {'name': 'Ken', 'food1': 'noodles', 'food2': 'rice'}
c = {'name': 'Max', 'food1': 'jello', 'food2': 'yogurt', 'food3': 'bananas', 'food4': 'milk'}

dcts = [a,b,c]

df = pd.concat((pd.Series(dct) for dct in dcts), axis=1).T.set_index('name')

#           food1   food2    food3 food4
# name
# Alison  bananas  apples    dates   NaN
# Ken     noodles    rice      NaN   NaN
# Max       jello  yogurt  bananas  milk
```

Comment: I was about to write a similar solution with just python, but pandas is great

Comment: Thanks, all - this was so so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

@Yakym Pirozhenko provided a great solution with pandas..

Here's one with just python and the standard library `csv`

**1.** Collect all possible keys:

```
allkeys = set()
for d in data:
    allkeys.extend(d.keys())
allkeys = list(allkeys) #freeze list order
```

**2.** Write to file

```
with open(csvfile, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=allkeys, restval='', extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    for d in data:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect